# In JavaScript, does using an array's length property produce integer math?

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, integer

I'm having trouble finding a resource that explicitly states what the return value of the length property is. I see vague references to it being an "integer" but nothing explicitly states that it would follow normal integer math expectations.

More precisely, if I use the length property in a modulo operation, will the result round down like typical integer math, or will it give me the float?

Comment: Javascript has no concept of an integer type -- only of a "number" type. If your modulo operation would yield a fractional result on an arbitrary integer, it will do the same with the value of `length`.

Comment: So then you would use Math.floor() and Math.ceil() to round up or down. Great, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript represents all numbers as 'double precision' floats.

So in a console, we can test that a length value is used as a float:

```
> a = [1,2,3,4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
> b = 9
9
> b/a.length
2.25
```

[MDN: value types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types)

[MDN: Number type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)